# Request for data dump to contain search and click logs

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

Would it be possible for the data dumps to include information about the search queries which were submitted to the site and questions which received click-throughs as a result?

That kind of data would be fascinating to use in information retrieval research.

Answer (score 1):

Three letters: AOL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL_search_data_scandal

Comment: Even without the session data (which is probably the biggest privacy concern), this data would still be very interesting/useful.